# What is the best way to load/save a configuration (potentially from disk) for a plugin in MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, mef

I'm building a plugin system for an emulator with MEF and now I'm trying to resolve an issue with loading and saving plugin settings, I've read this post [Populate MEF plugin with config data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142686/populate-mef-plugin-with-config-data) but I dont see a clear example.

To sum up, my main doubt is, how to read the configuration from disk, injecting should be easy, but after changing it, placing it back to disk doesn't seem an easy task.

Any ideas or examples?

Thank you!